# Couchbase n1ql match any of a sub document properties value

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Another question my document structure is :

```
{
  "desktop": {
    "default": {
      "s": {
        "camp": {
          "100112": 0,
          "100114": 0,
          "100122": 0
        },
        "score": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to find document where at least one of the camp properties is greater than 0. I starrt something like :

`select  * from my_bucket t where ANY camp_id IN desktop.default.s.camp SATISFIES camp_id.value > 0 END`

But of course it doesn't work :)

Any clues ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the use of the `ANY` ... `IN` ... `SATISFIES` clause.

The major problem with your query is that there isn't a `value` property in your temporary `camp_id` object. Instead, you can make use of the `OBJECT_VALUES` function (https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/objectfun.html) to pull the values from the `camp` poperties and compare them directly.

Your query will look similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM my_bucket 
WHERE 
  ANY camp_val 
  IN OBJECT_VALUES(default.desktop.default.s.camp) 
  SATISFIES camp_val > 0 
END
```